# Handling special characters (extended ascii) not displayed correctly when reading via pandas.read_csv()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that has extended ASCII characters like -> "Néw" , when I try to read this file and output the rows I get special character for e.g the above becomes -> "N�w".

I am using below command to read the file

```
df = pd.read_csv("temp.csv")
df.head(5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read_csv has a parameter 'encoding' which you would need to add to your code to get the string in text correctly .

Could you try using below and check if it works

```
df = pd.read_csv("temp.csv", encoding='utf-8')
df.head(5)
```

For checking list of all standard python encoding check this link- [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)